# express plotly - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, express, plot, plotly, percentage

I'm trying to plot data frame with percentage columns throw express plotly.

receiving

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

the columns:

```
    Meeting_inv pchanges_dax    Unscheduled_orde    pharmacy_nam    dis  yyyy/mm
0   1%             17%                5                  x           r  2011-1
1   2%             11%                1                  x           r  2011-2
2   5%             10%                7                  x           r  2011-6
3   10%            10%                5                  x           r  2011-7
4   2%             5%                14                  x           r  2011-8
```

the code :

```
    import plotly.express as px

px.scatter(df3, x="Meeting_inventory_target", y="Unscheduled_orders", animation_frame="yyyy/mm", animation_group="pharmacy_name",
           size="pchanges_dax", color="pharmacy_name", hover_name="district",
           log_x=True, size_max=100, range_x=[0.1,0.600], range_y=[0,30])
```

tried to convert columns - didn't helped.

tnx in advance

Comment: Could you please include the data as text, so one could reproduce the issue?

Comment: Is that all the data?  I'm seeing several errors such as: ValueError: Value of 'animation_group' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['Meeting_inventory_target', 'pchanges_dax'] but received: pharmacy_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the percent sign in the Meeting_inv and pchanges_dax columns. pandas (and plotly) perceive them as strings - rather than integers.

To solve it, run:

```
df["Meeting_inv"] = df.Meeting_inv.str.replace("%", "").astype(int)
df["pchanges_dax"] = df.pchanges_dax.str.replace("%", "").astype(int)
```

And then create the plot.